# KDE Plasma wallpaper doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma5, kdevelop

I use Manjaro Linux (Arch) with KDE. I want run "Simple Plasma Wallpaper with QML extension" in kdevelop, but that doesn't work. In README is written: "cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = MYPREFIX .. (MYPREFIX is where you install your Plasma setup, replace it accordingly)" I try so much dirs (/ usr / lib (or lib64) / qt / qml for example) and the result is one:

> "file:///usr/local/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.plasma.simple/contents/ui/main.qml" "Error loading QML file.\n28: module \"org.kde.plasma.private.simple\" is not installed\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct cmake for Arch Linux:

> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLIB_INSTALL_DIR=lib -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON ..

Warning: adapt for your project, may  crashed, because ( ".." ) compiling process happens outside current dir.